# Prove for any $n \geq 1$...Recursion?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am practicing review problems to practice from what what we last learnt in lecture, and I admit I am very lost.

I have no idea how to start these sort of problems

Prove for any $n \geq 1: F_1 + F_3 + F_5 + \cdots + F_{2n-1} = F_{2n}$ where $F_n$ is the $n$th term Fibonacci number.

I would greatly appreciate this answered so I can use it as a base to continue and answer the other problems myself. Or, if you would prefer instead of giving a full answer, please feel to give hints/advice to point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Um... $F_{2n} = F_{2n-1} + F_{2n-2}$. There's probably something wrong there. Do you mean
$$
F_1 + F_3 + F_5 + F_7 + \cdots + F_{2n-1} = F_{2n}
$$
by any chance?

Comment: Oh, wow, yes, did not even as I was typing that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since $F_n$ is a sequence defined recursively, you have $F_{2n} = F_{2n-1} + F_{2n-2}$. It is therefore a great idea to think about induction. Try to inspire yourself from
$$
F_1 + F_3 + \cdots + F_{2n-3} + F_{2n-1} = F_{2n} = F_{2n-1} + F_{2n-2}.
$$

Hope that helps,