# Sum of odd Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

Trying to prove that the sum of odd-index consecutive Fibonacci numbers is the next even-index Fibonacci number. I have a gap in my proof that I cannot figure out. I know that induction would be easier and I have already done it that way, I am looking to use alpha and beta.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i-1} = F_{2n}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i-1}&=\sum_{i=1}^1  \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\alpha^{2i-1}-\beta^{2i-1})\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^1\alpha^{2i-1}-\sum_{i=1}^1\beta^{2i-1}\right)\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[(\alpha^n-\beta^n)(\alpha^n+\beta^n)]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\alpha^{2n}-\beta^{2n})\\
&=F_{2n}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: There's a straightforward proof by induction.  Suppose that it's true for a given $n$ - i.e., that $F_{2n}=\sum_{i=1}^nF_{2i-1}$; then $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}F_{2i-1}=F_{2n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^nF_{2i-1}=F_{2n+1}+F_{2n}$...

Comment: I dont want to use induction. I need to use alpha and beta.

Comment: duplicate but the answers here are better: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673218/prove-for-any-n-geq-1-recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use (if $x^2-1\neq 0$):
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^{2i-1}=\frac{x^{2n+1}-x}{x^2-1} $$

Comment: Thanks for your correction

Comment: GREAT... This is what I was looking for but couldn't seem to find it...

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Induction is much easier, but if you really must use Binet’s formula, note that your summations are geometric, with ratios $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$, respectively; you can use the familiar formula for the sum of a finite geometric series. You also know that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy the equation $x^2-x-1=0$, so $\alpha^2-1=\alpha$ and $\beta^2-1=\beta$; this information will help you simplify the sums of the geometric progressions.

Comment: This helped... Thanks.

Comment: @Brad: You’re welcome.