# Let $(a_n)$ be a Fibonacci sequence , Prove that $a_1+a_3+a_5+\cdots+a_{2n-1} = a_{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

> Let $(a_n)$ be a Fibonacci sequence , Prove that $a_1+a_3+a_5+\cdots+a_{2n-1} = a_{2n}$

In this question $a_n$ is a Fibonacci sequence, I tried solving it with the PMI , problem arose when i was solving it for $P(n)=k+1$ , I could not make both of the sides equal.

Comment: What is a Fibonacci series?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/673218.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_1=1;a_2=1;a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2};\;n>2$

Induction

for $n=1$ it is true because $a_1=a_2$ by definition

now suppose it is true for $n$

$a_1+a_3+\ldots+a_{2n-1}=a_{2n}$

and let's prove it for $n+1$, that is

$\left(a_1+a_3+\ldots+a_{2n-1}\right)+a_{2n+1}=a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}=a_{2n+2}$

for the definition of the Fibonacci sequence

Hope this helps

Comment: hey,does a_2n + a_2n+1 = a_2n+2 , I dont quite understand it .

Comment: @Sarathy It is the definition of the Fibonacci sequence. See first line: each term is the sum of the previous two terms

Comment: so do i just leave it like that , apperantly this was the place i got stuck

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a_0=0,a_1=1$ we can always add $a_0$ for free, so we get
$$
\begin{split}
(a_0 + a_1) + a_3 + a_5 + \ldots + a_{2n-1}
 &= (a_2 + a_3) + a_5 + \ldots + a_{2n-1} \\
 &= a_4 + a_5 + \ldots + a_{2n-1} \\
 &= a_{2n}
\end{split}
$$
To make this formal, you can use Mathematical Induction.

Comment: Your proof is beautiful , but the problem specifies to use induction .